# Update two columns on the basis of the columns from other table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have the following table (table OptionTest) in which features and options are declared (a zero for visible means that the option of the feature is not visible and one means the option is visible. For value, a zero means that an option is not selected and a one means that an option is selected):

```
Feature_ID | OptionValue | value | visible
---------- | ----------- | ----- | -------
300        | 1           | 1     | 1
310        | 2           | 1     | 1
```

I want to use the following table (table OptionVisibility) to determine what options should not be visible (i.e. visible=0) in the table above (table OptionTest). I.e. visible from OptionValue 2 from Feature_ID 310 in the OptionTest table should be updated to 0 based on the contents of the OptionVisibility table, as there the value from OptionValue_1 1 from Feature_ID_1 300 is 1 and visible from OptionValue_2 from Feature_ID_2 is 0.

```
Feature_ID_1 | OptionValue_1 |value| Feature_ID_2 | OptionValue_2| visible |
------------ | ------------- |-----| ------------ | -------------| ------- |
300          | 1             | 1   | 310          | 2            |0        |
```

I eventuelly came up with the following query. However, I am still missing something as the query returns that 0 rows were affected. Any ideas?

```
UPDATE       
    OptionTest
    SET 
    OptionTest.Visible = OV2.visible
    FROM 
    OptionTest
    INNER JOIN OptionVisibility AS OV1 ON OptionTest.FeatureID = OV1.Feature_ID_1
    INNER JOIN OptionVisibility AS OV2 ON OptionTest.FeatureID = OV2.Feature_ID_2
    WHERE
    OptionTest.FeatureID=OV2.Feature_ID_2 AND OptionTest.OptionValue = OV2.OptionValue_2
```

### UPDATE

Found the solution. I had to use left join:

```
UPDATE       
    OptionTest
    SET 
    OptionTest.Visible = OV2.visible
    FROM 
    OptionTest
    LEFT JOIN OptionVisibility AS OV1 ON OptionTest.FeatureID = OV1.Feature_ID_1
    LEFT JOIN OptionVisibility AS OV2 ON OptionTest.FeatureID = OV2.Feature_ID_2
    WHERE
    OptionTest.FeatureID=OV2.Feature_ID_2 AND OptionTest.OptionValue = OV2.OptionValue_2
```

### UPDATE

Thought the solution worked, but of course the query in its current state does not check where the value is set to 1 (in this case the query should check if the value from optionvalue 1 from Feature_ID 300 is set to 1).

### UPDATE

Finally solved the puzzle

```
UPDATE       
OptionTest
SET OptionTest.Visible = Case When (select OptionTest.value from 
                                        OptionTest 
INNER JOIN OptionVisibility 
                                        ON OptionTest.FeatureID = OptionVisibility .Feature_ID_1  
                                        where OptionTest.ConfigurationID=66071 
                                        AND OptionTest.FeatureID = OptionVisibility.Feature_ID_1 
                                        AND OptionTest.OptionValue=OptionVisibility.OptionValue_1 
                                        AND OptionTest.value=1)=1 Then 0 Else 1 End
FROM OptionTest
INNER JOIN OptionVisibility ON OptionTest.FeatureID = OptionVisibility.Feature_ID_2
WHERE
OptionTest.OptionValue = OptionVisibility.OptionValue_2
AND OptionTest.ConfigurationID = 66071
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these..

```
 UPDATE tableOne 
       SET tableOne.Feature_ID= tableTwo.Feature_ID_1,
tableOne.OptionValue= tableTwo.OptionValue_1 ,
tableOne.value= tableTwo.value_1 ,
tableOne.visible= tableTwo.visible  FROM tableOne INNER JOIN  tableTwo ON tableOne .Feature_ID = tableTwo.Feature_ID_1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.